# Circular gravitational field

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, black-holes, spacetime-dimensions, accretion-disk

Why do all heavy masses in the universe always have circular gravitational field and why do objects 'falling' under their spacetime influence always fall in circles? For example,  accretion disks outside black holes are in a circular shape. Why don't they fall directly inside the black hole without forming circular disks?

Comment: Big question, far too big for _me_ to answer.  Look up angular velocity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by circular gravitational field, gravitational fields are radially directed lines that point inward towards masses. The equipotential lines are circular.